# Export annotation text bubbles

Tags: qgis2web

Is there a way to export annotation text bubbles with qgis2web?
Or is there an alternative to implement this?

[image: e.g. Start, Ziel, Verpflegung....]

Exported:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative I can recommend NextGIS cloud Web GIS. Use NextGIS Connect to create your web map exactly as it looks like in QGIS.

- Get your free web GIS here: http://nextgis.com/
- QGIS Plugin is here: http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/nextgis_connect/
- Documentation: http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngcom/source/toc.html

Note: Cloud GIS and NextGIS Connect both use 2.18 QGIS rendering engine. QGIS 3 is not available now.

**Disclosure**: I'm developer at NextGIS.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, this is not supported in qgis2web. You can open a feature request at https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues